# how to avoid sudo su -s /bin/bash jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I used to be able to change to jenkins user from root by doing
`su jenkins`

but with my new jenkins installation, I have to do  sudo su -s /bin/bash jenkins

does anyone know how I can just do su - jenkins again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the shell specified in /etc/passwd for the jenkins user.  You can do so by running something like:

```
grep jenkins /etc/passwd
```

The output will look similar to this:

```
jenking:1001:1001::/usr/local/jenkins:/bin/false
```

The last field is the login shell of the user. Here you can see it is set to /bin/false which will immediately exit.

The solution is to specify which shell to use as you described:

```
su -s /bin/bash jenkins
```

Or modify the login shell of the jenkins user with "usermod(8)" (executed as a root user) :

```
usermod -s /bin/bash jenkins
```

Then `grep jenkins /etc/passwd` should now output something like:

```
jenkins:1001:1001::/usr/local/jenkins:/bin/bash
```

After which. `su - jenkins` will work as you expect.

Comment: And you may think about if you really want a jenkins shell. For config files editing as root may make sense (because then processes running as jenkins cannot modify it), when running commands as jenkins ``sudo`` may be a better alternative.